# Light the screen after dismissing ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity in which I'm using ProgressDialog.

After performing `dialog.dismiss()`, the screen remains grey until the user press the screen and then it gets light.

How can I make the screen light after the `dialog.dismiss()` command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int brightnessMode = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
if (brightnessMode == Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC) {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
}

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = 0.5F; // set 50% brightness
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```